Protocol requirements
It seems that I have fulfilled requirements of protocol EveryUserDocument in class GetListItem, however the code doesn't compile returning me error: Type 'GetListItem' does not conform to protocol 'EveryUserDocument'. Can somebody explain why and how to do a workaround?
public class GetListItem: NSObject, Codable, EveryUserDocument {
    public let id: Int
    public let relations: [GetListItemRelation]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case relations
    }
}

public class GetListItemRelation: NSObject, Codable, EveryUserDocumentRelation {
    public let id: Int
    public let objectClass: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case objectClass
    }
}

protocol EveryUserDocument: Equatable {
    var id: Int { get }
    var relations: [EveryUserDocumentRelation] { get }
}

protocol EveryUserDocumentRelation {
    var id: Int { get }
    var objectClass: String { get }
}


Your class does not fullfill Equatable which is required by EveryUserDocument

public let relations: [GetListItemRelation]

doesn't satisfy
public let relations: [EveryUserDocumentRelation]

Because it thinks of the type specifically any EveryUserDocumentRelation. Even if GetListItemRelation conforms to it, it wont satisfy the protocol requirement. To fix it use associatedtype in EveryUserDocument protocol.
protocol EveryUserDocument: Equatable {
    associatedtype UserDocumentRelation: EveryUserDocumentRelation
    
    var id: Int { get }
    var relations: [UserDocumentRelation] { get }
}


thanks for your answer, I'll give it a try later and let you know
